# Laravel 4 Installing dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How do I install [Laravel DomPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)?

I updated my Laravel's `composer.json` from this:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "maatwebsite/excel": " ~1.2.1"
},
```

To this:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "maatwebsite/excel": " ~1.2.1",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.5.*"
},
```

And then ran this command:

```
composer update barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.5.*
```

But it always throws **"don't install laravel 4.2"** like that and the composer fails to update.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The very first line from the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) readme says:

> **DOMPDF Wrapper for Laravel 5**

The second one states:

> **For Laravel 4.x, check the [0.4 branch](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/0.4)!**

Which means you need to add the `0.4.*` version to you `composer.json`, for the package to work with Laravel 4:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "maatwebsite/excel": " ~1.2.1",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.4.*"
},
```

Comment: So i should use `composer update "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.r.*"` in composer ??

Comment: Yes, just do what you did before, but instead of using version `0.5.*`, use version `0.4.*`.

Comment: Or simply follow the instructions on the page for the Laravel 4 branch of the package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/0.4.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.4"
```

you not use packege laravel 5 for laravel 4